# How do you access a variable outside a function in swift

Tags: function, variables, swift

I am trying to access inputAC and inputB outside my function getVariables and I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code I am working with but it does currently work.

```
func getVariables () {
        var inputAC = textFieldAC.text.toInt()
        var inputB = textFieldB.text.toInt()

    }

    var ac = inputAC
    var b = inputB
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not because they're local variables?

Comment: I am taking a course, but I am not too advanced with it yet. I was trying to find a direct answer to this question, but I could not find one. I will try to stick to more advanced questions in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return the values from the function.  Here is one way to do it by returning them in a tuple:

```
func getVariables () -> (Int?, Int?) {
    var inputAC = textFieldAC.text.toInt()
    var inputB = textFieldB.text.toInt()
    return (inputAC, inputB)
}

var (ac, b) = getVariables()

// Since the values are optionals, you can use optional binding to
// safely unwrap the value.
if let acval = ac {
    println("ac value is \(acval)")
} else {
    println("alas, ac was nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These variables which are in `getVariables` method can not be access outside this method,  because these are method local variables. Scope for accessing them is only for that method.
If you want to access them declare them as property or instance variables in class....

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to instance this variables in class. If swift is not so different to java, you could declare them as class variables and set them in your method. Then, outside your method, you could access them with a

(this is java code, I'm sorry, but I try to give you the general idea)

In the class you should do something like this:

```
Int ac; int b;
```

In the method do something like this:

```
this.setInputAc(inputAc);
this.setInputB(inputAc);
```

Outside you should do something like this:

```
ac = this.getInputAc();  
b = this.getInputB();
```

Also, declare your setter and getter for each variable

Just to give you the general idea.